# How to change number stored to a plain text format in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formatting

I have numbers stored in a sheet as `(xxx) xxx-xxxx`.  I want to remove all formatting and make it just `xxxxxxxxxx`.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try:

```
=regexreplace(A1,"\D","")
```

[REGEXREPLACE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)